How to handle priority in Scripy with multiple start urls
I have this code:
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "myspider"
    start_urls = [
        "link_a",
        "link_b"
        # there will be more links later
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        item = {
            "url": response.url,
        }

        link_to_c = response.xpath("//a[contains(@href, '/abc/')]/@href").get()
        if link_to_c is not None:
            yield response.follow(link_to_c, callback=self.parse_link_to_c, meta={"item": item}, priority=1)

        link_to_d = response.xpath("//a[contains(@href, '/def/')]/@href").get()
        yield response.follow(side_effects_link, callback=self.parse_link_to_d, meta={"item": item})


    def parse_link_to_c(self, response):
        item = response.meta["item"]

        item["..._c"] = ...
        print("parse_link_to_c", item["url"])

    def parse_link_to_d(self, response):
        item = response.meta["item"]

        item["..._d"] = ...
        print("parse_link_to_d", item["url"])
        return item


class WebscraperPipeline:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = {}

    def open_spider(self, spider):
        self.file = open("items.jsonl", "wb")
        self.exporter = JsonLinesItemExporter(self.file)
        self.exporter.start_exporting()

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        self.exporter.finish_exporting()
        self.file.close()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        print(item)
        # self.exporter.export_item(item)
        return item

I'd like to do for each url in start_urls:

parse link_to_c
store to item in parse_link_to_c
parse link_to_d
store to item in parse_link_to_d
pass item to WebscraperPipeline

I don't care about the order of start_urls, but I care about the order of inner scraping (inside parse method). I am trying to pass 'whole' item to WebscraperPipeline, so with everything I parsed stored inside it.
The problem is it doesn't follow the priority I've defined in follow. Here is the print outputs:
parse_link_to_d link_a
parse_link_to_c link_a
parse_link_to_c link_b
parse_link_to_d link_b

Sometime it runs correct, sometime it doesn't.

Does this answer your question? Scrapy does not execute requests in order of priority values
